# Automation - Page not changing after JQuery Execution on select2 item

Tags: java, automation, webdriver, jquery-select2

Automating with Selenium, I have a page in where I have to access to a modal. Inside it, I have a select2 drop down. I use a JS Executor to interact with it, allowing me to select it's options, which works fine.

The problem that I have is that when I make a selection, there are some fields that appear or disappear depending on what I choose; but as I have to use the JS Executor, seems that the page does not detect the selection (although it IS done), and therefore the fields that should appear/disappear don't behave correctly; making the tests fail.

Is there any way to make the modal, or at least the section in where the select2 drop down is, to either 'refresh' or show the fields that I will need to interact with?

Comment: Looks like the click on dropdown option triggers some ajax/js on page to draw new fields. So, as an option try to figure out the code that must run to change the DOM and execute it via js executor

Comment: Yep, I have been searching around and seems the best thing yo do. Could you post it as answer, though? It server me as kickstarter to search what to do, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the click on dropdown option triggers some ajax/js on page to draw new fields. So, as an option try to figure out the code that must run to change the DOM and execute it via js executor

Comment: Really many thanks, I discovered quite a lot with this, seems I was kind of blocked and ran out of ideas until realizing what I really needed.